# window.clipboardData permissions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clipboard

I'm creating web application on ASP.NET WebForms, and one of my tasks is copy/paste data to excel from web page. I/m using window.clipboardData, and it works for my user (local admin). But for other users it doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser level permission, that need to be set depending of the browser.
In the documentation of your application you need to specify where and how to enable it on the browser.

I recommend you to explore each browser options, for your documentation.
For Internet Explorer you can go to Internet Options>Security>Add the Website/link to the trusted sites (Make sure https checkbox is checked, if your website is not using https). After adding it, go to Custom Level in the same window. It will pop another window, you can explore all the options for any other think you may need. The option to allow access to clipboard show be "Allow Programmatic clipboard access" and set it to enabled.

It may be a ActiveX Control that can make it automatically, but will work only for Internet Explorer.